# Searching for text in Selenium using Perl

Tags: perl, selenium

In order to ensure a user has authenticated successfully on this web page I'm writing tests for, his/her login id will be displayed -- below is the HTML using firepath when the user successfully authenticates.

```
<a href="#">
 user2@user2
 ::after
</a>
```

Below is the HTML using page source

```
<a href="#">
 user2@store2
</a>
```

The reason why I posted two sources of HTML because I'm not quite sure which source will aid in the troubleshooting. The error I am getting is

```
Timed out after 30000ms
```

Below is the Perl code I'm using. I'm using the WWW::Selenium module.

```
my $locator = q{//a[contains(@href, "user2")]};
my $ret = $sel->wait_for_text_present($locator, 2000);
```

Below partially works but I would like to see the user's login ID and I don't want to use click.

```
ret = $sel->click('//a[contains(@href,"#")]');
```

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Comment: Have you tried `$ret = $driver->find_element('user2@user2', 'link_text');`?

Comment: You're testing whether the value of the `href` attribute contains `"user2"`. It doesn't. Test the `text` inside the `a` element instead.

Comment: @JeffC, in the WWW::Selenium documentation, there is no `find_element` function but there is a `get_attribute` which didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with WWW::Selenium so I repurposed an answer below without looking at the docs. But... I did look at the docs and found  that one of the locators is by link text, e.g. `link=textPattern:Select the link (anchor) element which contains text matching the specified pattern. link=The link text`. You should be able to look for the link text, "user2@user2", with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry as I do not know Perl.

In java I would use the getText() on the locator to get the username you are looking for.

Use the code inside your click and set the locator to that path.

Edit Try this:

```
$mylocator= $driver->find_element('//a[contains(@href,"#")]');
```

Then use getText() on that element.

This may be in Perl:

```
$username= $mylocator->get_text();
```

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reviewing the module's documentation of WWW::Selenium, there is a function I overlooked, below is the code and function that resolved my issue.

```
$sel->is_text_present("user2\@store2");
```